# Unable to run includes() method on string returned by fs.readFileSync()

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

having a bit of trouble:

`let data = fs.readFileSync(pathToCsv, "utf8");`

the value of data comes out to be:

```
clan,mem1,mem2,mem3,mem4,language,managerID,serverJoinedDate
pm,
pm
```

(through console.log())

but still `data.toString().includes("pm")` is false.

Here is my full code:

```
const filter = (m) => m.author.bot === false;
      await ogMessage.author.dmChannel
        .awaitMessages(filter, {
          max: 1,
          time: 60000,
        })
        .then((collected) => {
          if (clans[parseInt(collected.toJSON()[0].content) - 1]) {
            let clan = clans[parseInt(collected.toJSON()[0].content) - 1];
            let data = fs.readFileSync(pathToCsv, "utf8");
            console.log(typeof clan);
            // let reg = new RegExp(clan, "g");
            // let count = (data.match(reg) || []).length;
            if (data.split(",").includes(clan)) {
              ogMessage.author.send(
                "People from this clan are already registered!\nPlease contact the hosts for help!"
              );
              return;
            } else {
              teamCheck = true;
            }
          } else {
            ogMessage.author.send("Invalid Clan! Please try again!");
            return;
          }
        })
        .catch((collected) => {
          try {
            console.log("Error" + collected);
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
          }
        });
      if (teamCheck === false) {
        return;
      }
```

I have tried splitting the data, using regular expressions but nothing seems to work on the string returned by
`readFileSync()`

PS. I am making a discord bot.

Comment: In the data example you provided, there is a space in front of `pm`.

Comment: The space before pm is actually supposed to be a new line, I'll update it in the question

Comment: Try `data.split(",").map(it => it.trim()).includes(clan)`

Comment: It doesn't work :( there is a newline before pm as i previously mentioned

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log(data)` and `console.log(clan)` ?

Comment: `console.log(data)`:

`clan,mem1,mem2,mem3,mem4,language,managerID,serverJoinedDate`
`\npm,`
`\npm`
("\n" is not visible in console, I am just adding to help you ubnderstand that there is a newline before both the "pm"s)
and `console.log(clan)` gives `pm`

Comment: Possibilities I could ever think of: 1. `String.prototpye.includes` get override somewhere  2. There are invisible characters between `p` and `m`. Maybe try `fs.readFileSync(pathToCsv, "hex");` to inspect the raw bytes.

Comment: I logged my clans array and got this `[
  'pm\r',
  'ar\r',
  'lz\r',
  'gm\r',
  'kr\r',
  'dp-divinity parcel\r',
  'abx'
]` Maybe the `\r` is causing something since I am reading this info from another txt file and then splitting to  form an array

Comment: I tried logging the bytes and this is what I get: 
`636c616e2c6d656d312c6d656d322c6d656d332c6d656d342c6c616e67756167652c6d616e6167657249442c7365727665724a6f696e6564446174650d0a706d2c0d0a706d2c` I don't know what to make of it

Answer (score 0):

In the source string you have `pm` with a space before it. That's why after calling `split(","` you end up with the element `" pm"` in the result array and "pm" is not equal to it.
You just need to trim spaces in all elements before searching some string in it

Comment: Actually it is supposed to be a new line before `pm` for some reason it doesn't show up correctly in the question but even if I do a simple `data.includes("pm")`, it still doesn't work but pm is there in the string right?

Comment: `var a = 'clan,mem1,mem2,mem3,mem4,language,managerID,serverJoinedDate pm, pm'` and `a.toString().includes('pm')` returns `true`

Comment: Yes but it returns false in my case

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the clans array.
I was defining it as such:

`var clans = fs.readFileSync(pathToData, "utf8").split("\n");`

but the problem was that the `readFileSync()` method added an `"\r"` after every string of the array. That is why it was not able to match the clan string to the data

So what worked was `var clans = fs.readFileSync(pathToData, "utf8").split("\r\n");`

Now, the array includes only the string, and the includes() method can find a match!